# How to egl offscreen render to an image on linux?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I'm trying to use egl to do offscreen rendering to an image.

my code doesn't generate any error. the egl part seems to be correct, the fbo is also complete. but when I read pixels using glReadPixels, I always get a black image (I cleared the entire scene with red, so the image should be red too).

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Also, I noticed that glRenderbufferStorage can only support 16bit color depth. GL_RGBA8 is consider an invalid parameter for this function. Isn't 16bit a bit low for serious opengl application?

My environment is Ubuntu 14.10 with mesa and intel graphics.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QImage>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #define CONTEXT_ES20

    #ifdef CONTEXT_ES20
        EGLint ai32ContextAttribs[] = { EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
                                                     EGL_NONE };
    #endif

    // Step 1 - Get the default display.
    EGLDisplay eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay((EGLNativeDisplayType)0);

    // Step 2 - Initialize EGL.
    eglInitialize(eglDisplay, 0, 0);

    #ifdef CONTEXT_ES20
    // Step 3 - Make OpenGL ES the current API.
    eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_ES_API);

    // Step 4 - Specify the required configuration attributes.
    EGLint pi32ConfigAttribs[5];
    pi32ConfigAttribs[0] = EGL_SURFACE_TYPE;
    pi32ConfigAttribs[1] = EGL_WINDOW_BIT;
    pi32ConfigAttribs[2] = EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE;
    pi32ConfigAttribs[3] = EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT;
    pi32ConfigAttribs[4] = EGL_NONE;
    #else
    EGLint pi32ConfigAttribs[3];
    pi32ConfigAttribs[0] = EGL_SURFACE_TYPE;
    pi32ConfigAttribs[1] = EGL_WINDOW_BIT;
    pi32ConfigAttribs[2] = EGL_NONE;
    #endif

    // Step 5 - Find a config that matches all requirements.
    int iConfigs;
    EGLConfig eglConfig;
    eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, pi32ConfigAttribs, &eglConfig, 1,
                                                    &iConfigs);

    if (iConfigs != 1) {
        printf("Error: eglChooseConfig(): config not found.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Step 6 - Create a surface to draw to.
    EGLSurface eglSurface;
    eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig,
                                  (EGLNativeWindowType)NULL, NULL);

    // Step 7 - Create a context.
    EGLContext eglContext;
    #ifdef CONTEXT_ES20
        eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig, NULL,
                                               ai32ContextAttribs);
    #else
        eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig, NULL, NULL);
    #endif

    // Step 8 - Bind the context to the current thread
    eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext);

    GLuint fboId = 0;
    GLuint renderBufferWidth = 1280;
    GLuint renderBufferHeight = 720;

    // create a framebuffer object
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

    // create a texture object
    /*  GLuint textureId;
     glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);                             
     //GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
     glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
     glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT, GL_TRUE); // automatic mipmap
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight, 0,
                  GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
     // attach the texture to FBO color attachment point
     glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                         GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);
     */
     qDebug() << glGetError();
     GLuint renderBuffer;
     glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer);
     glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
     qDebug() << glGetError();
     glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                           GL_RGB565,
                           renderBufferWidth,
                           renderBufferHeight);
     qDebug() << glGetError();
     glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                               GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                               GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                               renderBuffer);

      qDebug() << glGetError();
      GLuint depthRenderbuffer;
      glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
      glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
      glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16,     renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight);
      glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

      // check FBO status
      GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
      if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
          printf("Problem with OpenGL framebuffer after specifying color render buffer: \n%x\n", status);
      } else {
          printf("FBO creation succedded\n");
  }

  glClearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  qDebug() << eglSwapBuffers(   eglDisplay, eglSurface);
  int size = 4 * renderBufferHeight * renderBufferWidth;
  printf("print size");
  printf("size %d", size);
  qDebug() << size;

  unsigned char *data2 = new unsigned char[size];

  glReadPixels(0,0,renderBufferWidth,renderBufferHeight,GL_RGB, GL_RGB565, data2);

  QImage image(data2, renderBufferWidth,  renderBufferHeight,renderBufferWidth*2, QImage::Format_RGB16);

  image.save("result.png");


  qDebug() << "done";


  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This isn't a "serious OpenGL application", it's an OpenGL ES 2.0 application. You put up with a lot of limitations when writing software for ES 2.0, like a very limited set of required color renderable formats.

Comment: Can you try `GL_RGBA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` for the `glReadPixels()` arguments? The format/type you're using is not guaranteed to be supported in ES 2.0.

Comment: HAHA! you are so right, using GL_RGBA/GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, it worked! Because I found that the color buffer can only be 16bit, I thought when I read it back, I need to use a matching format. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 has a very limited number of formats/types that are supported for `glReadPixels()`. The ones you are trying to use are not guaranteed to be supported:

```
glReadPixels(0 ,0, renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight,
             GL_RGB, GL_RGB565, data2);
```

Only two formats/types are supported:

- `GL_RGBA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.
- An implementation dependent combination.

The format and type of the implementation dependent combination can be queried with:

```
GLint format = 0, type = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT, &format);
glGetIntegerv(GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE, &type);
```

This can give you one of the following combinations:

- `GL_RGB`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.
- `GL_RGB`/`GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5`.
- `GL_RGBA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4`.
- `GL_RGBA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1`.
- `GL_ALPHA`/`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

So the combination you tried to use **could** be supported by an implementation, if it returns the corresponding values from the `glGetIntegerv()` calls above. However, there was a subtle but important error in the arguments of your `glReadPixels()` call even if it is supported: `GL_RGB565` is a value for a *format*, while the 6th argument is a *type*. The call would have to be:

```
glReadPixels(0 ,0, renderBufferWidth, renderBufferHeight,
             GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, data2);
```